# a problem looks like 2d heat flow equations

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I shared direct problem with at image. I can't solve this problem and only see something about it at internet. It was looks as a $2D$ heat flow examples. But I can't do anything still. That problem under the Laplace equations at my notes. we solve an example before this with seperating variables method. But I can't apply it at this and sorry for my English.
$$
{\partial^{2}\operatorname{u}\left(x,y\right) \over \partial x^{2}} +
{\partial^{2}\operatorname{u}\left(x,y\right) \over \partial y^{2}} +
{\partial\operatorname{u}\left(x,y\right) \over \partial x} = 0,\qquad
\left\{\begin{array}{l}
{\displaystyle\operatorname{u}\left(x,0\right) =
\operatorname{u}\left(x,\pi\right) =
\operatorname{u}\left(0,y\right) = 0}
\\[1mm]
{\displaystyle\operatorname{u}\left(\pi,y\right) = \sin\left(y\right)}
\\[1mm]
{\displaystyle x,y \in \left(0,\pi\right)}
\end{array}\right.
$$
$$
\mbox{Answer is :}\qquad\operatorname{u}\left(x,y\right) =
{\rm e}^{\left(\pi - x\right)/2}\,\,\sin\left(y\right)\,
{\sinh\left(\,\sqrt{\,{5}\,}\,x/2\right) \over \sinh\left(\,\sqrt{\,{5}\,}\,\pi/2\right)}
$$

http://i66.tinypic.com/2r2yzow.jpg

edit:added another link for problem because I can't see the first photo

Comment: Please edit your post with MathJax. People are more likely to answer it when we don’t have to click on a picture.

Comment: i tried to make it but there i have problem about e upper part

Comment: @user510852 Use ^{} to for powers and _{} for subscripts. For example, e^{- ( \pi - x ) } with \$ \$ around it gives $e^{-(\pi - x)}$. Also, use \sin, \cos \sinh etc for $\sin$, $\cos$ and $\sinh$. Finally, \frac{}{} for fractions.

Comment: thanks, i think it is better now.

Comment: I'm not sure if you've solved it by now, but it can be done via eigenfunction expansion or separation of variables.

Comment: no i cant solve it, still need. that du/dx thing makes problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

I'll do this via separation of variables, but I'm going to note that it's doable via eigenfunction expansion too.

Assuming $u(x, y) = X(x)Y(y)$, we arrive at the equations

$$\begin{cases}
X'' + X' - \lambda^2 X = 0 & X(0)=0, X(\pi)=\sin{y}\\
Y'' + \lambda^2 Y = 0 & Y(0)=0, Y(\pi)=0
\end{cases}
$$

We can immediately see that $Y(y) = \sin{(\lambda y)}$, so that $\lambda = n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Solving the other equation, we're a little more careful, note that

$X_n(x) = e^{-\frac{1}{2}x}(A_n e^{\frac{x}{2}\sqrt{4n^2+1}}+B_n e^{-\frac{x}{2}\sqrt{4n^2+1}})$, and that the condition that $X(0)=0$ implies $A_n = -B_n$, so  it must be that $X_n(x) = e^{-\frac{1}{2}x}A_n\sinh{(\frac{x}{2}\sqrt{4n^2+1})}$

Thus our solution is of the form 
$$u(x,y) = e^{-\frac{1}{2}x}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n\sinh{\left(\frac{x}{2}\sqrt{4n^2+1}\right)}\sin{(ny)}$$

In order to satisfy the last condition, we require

$$e^{-\frac{1}{2}\pi}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n\sinh{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\sqrt{4n^2+1}\right)}\sin{(ny)}=\sin{y}$$

but the only way for this to happen is when $A_n = 0$ for $n>1$. Solving for the coefficient, we have $A_1 = e^{\frac{1}{2}\pi}\text{csch}{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\sqrt{5}\right)}$

Thus, our solution collapses to be
$$u(x, y) = e^{\frac{1}{2}(\pi-x)}\sin{(y)}\sinh{\left(\frac{x}{2}\sqrt{5}\right)}\text{csch}{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\sqrt{5}\right)}$$

Comment: thanks for it. Now is it full answer or you dont write some steps ? because i dont understand how you get this : $$ X_n(x) = e^{-\frac{1}{2}x}(A_n e^{\frac{x}{2}\sqrt{4n^2+1}}+B_n e^{-\frac{x}{2}\sqrt{4n^2+1}}) $$

Comment: You have to solve a second order linear ODE, I would suggest reviewing your differential equations if you can't remember how to solve those types.